# Identify BLE beacon service ( to enable notification, if available )

Tags: service, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

Just got started on BLE Beacons and wrote up a small program to locate beacons and list some services etc. The following is the result that I can print in the console.log

```
BLE service: 
  Service handle: 43
  uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
BLE service: 
  Service handle: 44
  uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
      descriptor: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
BLE service: 
  Service handle: 45
  uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
BLE service: 
  Service handle: 46
  uuid: 0000c050-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c051-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c052-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c053-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c054-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c055-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c056-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c057-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c058-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c059-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c05a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
      descriptor: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c05b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c05c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c05d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
BLE service: 
  Service handle: 47
  uuid: 0000c090-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c091-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
      descriptor: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c092-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c093-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c094-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: 0000c095-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
BLE service: 
  Service handle: 48
  uuid: f000ffc0-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
    characteristic: f000ffc1-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
      descriptor: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
      descriptor: 00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    characteristic: f000ffc2-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
      descriptor: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
      descriptor: 00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

These beacons are basically transmitting 2 values - temperature and voltage of the beacon itself. While I am up reading some more notes, I was wondering if someone could point to which of these UUIDs/characteristic that I need to focus on, to be able to get the temperature and voltage readings? As I do more reading and research, I would really appreciate if any experienced developer could give some pointers? Basically I need to enable the notification on the temperature and voltage service. I can figure out from the BLE libraries how to enable the notification but how do I locate / point to the correct service/characteristic/descriptor etc? Thanks once again

I got an Arduino board with ble to scan and capture some data from the beacons

```
[ADV    22587] Packet received from 50:65:83:10:E6:3A
       PAYLOAD 30 bytes
               02-01-06-1A-FF-6A-00-0F-75-E9-D5-AD-15-DF-FB-48-01-52-4E-8A-4B-B9-3D-0F-00-1E-3B-9E-FF-2C
          RSSI -68 dBm
      ADV TYPE Connectable undirected
 MAN SPEC DATA 6A-00-0F-75-E9-D5-AD-15-DF-FB-48-01-52-4E-8A-4B-B9-3D-0F-00-1E-3B-9E-FF-2C

[SR     22618] Packet received from 50:65:83:10:E6:3A
       PAYLOAD 22 bytes
               12-09-69-57-45-45-43-41-52-45-20-54-65-6D-70-20-50-61-6C-02-0A-00
          RSSI -68 dBm
      ADV TYPE Connectable undirected
 COMPLETE NAME Temp mini Sensor
  TX PWR LEVEL 0
```

Any pointers on how I should continue from here? Trying to just get a hang of it ... just that elusive lead ... and I think I'd have understanding of what's going on :)

Comment: The first three Services are Generic Access, Generic Attribute, and Device Information (see here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services). The rest is manufacturer specific and only the manufacturer can tell you what is going on there.

Comment: Okay thanks Nebr. I am trying to isolate the services ( like the ones you just mentioned and there are 3 of them left, which I think could be the suspects :) It's probably not   Service handle: 48
  uuid: f000ffc0-0451-4000-b000-000000000000 so I'll further probe the remaining two. Seems I am getting closer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth Gatt services simply allow you to read and write characteristics on the Bluetooth peripheral.  Typically peripherals are designed so that writing certain patterns to certain characteristics controls what the peripheral will do.

To take an example from your question, writing some pattern to some characteristics might control whether the connected Bluetooth central is notified of changes in temperature and/or voltage, based on crossing a threshold or at a regular interval.

The key thing to understand is that **the way you configure the Bluetooth peripheral all depends its system design.  It is not standard.**  You really need **documentation from the manufacturer** to tell you how to do this.  Without such documentation, you are basically reverse-engineering the Bluetooth peripheral.

It may be helpful to get a better answer to your question to identify the manufacturer and model of this beacon device.  If you don't see any documentation on the manufacturer's website, the perhaps the manufacturer will answer this question directly, or somebody else who has reverse-engineered the device will do so.

Comment: thanks for the info. I am shooting emails to manufacturer but total silence from their side. I am starting to think that the manufacturer is keen to promote their own app even though they have not anywhere explicitly mentioned that. I am going a little brute force now by writing/enabling notifications on every service that I can discover :) Luckily this beacon just does 2, so I may perhaps get there with some trial and error. Once again really appreciate the pointers - at least gives me some clues and confirms certain things.